# How can I derive a noun from the verb "percorrere"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, single-words, nouns

I've observed that some nouns can be derived from Italian verbs by combining them with the suffix -aggio. For instance,  "lavare" --> "lavaggio", "passare" --> "passaggio", "atterrare" --> "atterraggio", "monitorare" --> "monitoraggio". Is there a noun derived from "percorrere" in this or in another way?

I ask this because I've obtained the expression "monitoraggio di insieme" from Google Translate and I would like to change it into something with "percorrere" instead of "monitorare", something similar to "percorrere l'insieme" but with a noun instead of "percorrere".

Comment: Welcome again su Italian.SE, @LolFlo! I don't understand your question. May you please give some more details? For instance, you can add a construction similar to the one you are asking for.

Comment: Do you refer, for example, to "lavare" --> "lavaggio", "passare" --> "passaggio"? Note that not all Italian verbs have such derivatives.

Comment: According to  [Treccani dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/aggio_res-cfe93bf0-000c-11de-9d89-0016357eee51), this happens only with verbs whose infinitive finish in *-are*, but not with all of them.

Comment: i don't want to copy str8 from translate google again which ,just now , gave me the translation 'monitoraggio di insieme', I quickly changed to "percorerre il insieme ' instead, is that equal though- from what I remember in Spanish class it is.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't understand what you're asking. I'm sorry, but your last comment is incomprehensible for me.

Comment: It becomes "percorso".

Comment: I've changed the text of your post and reopened it. I hope this is what you are asking for. If it's not, please edit your question.

Comment: @TommySimo: Would you like to add an answer?

Comment: @TommySimo I think it should be _percorrenza_ instead of _percorso_, since it represents the act of percorrere. (But sincerely I'm not completely confident with this assumption)

Comment: Sorry - the present participle is new for me because I used to use other languages - if there is a gerund form for verbal nouns, and a present/past participle for adjectives, doesn't that mean I use " ~ il percorrendo "?

Comment: @LolFlo: I have a hard time understanding your comments. If you are asking whether *_il percorrendo_ might denote “the act of _percorrere_”, the answer is no. The verbal mood _gerundio_ in Italian is quite different from English gerund; it has some common uses, but making nouns out of verbs isn't one. If anything, you might say _il percorrere_ (the infinitive used as a noun) but, although more or less understandable, it still sounds unusual. For many verbs, one has to learn the noun or nouns that denote that action, in this case both _percorso_ and _percorrenza_, with different meanings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suffix *-aggio* is ​​indeed used to derive nouns from verbs, but, as explained by [Treccani dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/aggio_res-cfe93bf0-000c-11de-9d89-0016357eee51), this happens only with verbs whose infinitive finish in *-are* and not with all of them.

As said by @TommySimo in their comment, the word you are looking for is probably ["percorso"](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/P/percorso.shtml), which is the past participle of "percorrere", but also a noun which means route, way, path, itinerary, track, route..., both in a literal and figurative way. You can perfectly say "percorso di insieme".

As mentioned by @abarisone, there exists also the noun ["percorrenza"](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/P/percorrenza.shtml), but, as you can see in the linked dictionary, it's used more specifically for the way, distance or time traveled by a means of transport (for a train, for instance) in a given period of time.

Comment: Can I just go back to using "percorrere l'insieme" - - > "tracking the sets" as I would have in Spanish ?

Comment: The problem is that I  don't know what do you mean with "tracking the sets".

Comment: In my paper I used the sentence "tracking which sets are open and which are closed is the most important thing ..."

Comment: @LolFlo:  Are you talking about topology? And what exactly do you mean with "tracking"?

Comment: Yes - however I just wrote my paper in Vietnamese and I am translating it into Italian so that is determines my vocabulary quite a bit. I also want to have conversations with a friend who is Italian..

Comment: @LolFlo: But, what do you mean with "track"? If you are writing about topology, it probably doesn't mean neither "percorrere" nor "monitorare".

Comment: Cataloging \ tracking which sets are open and closed in different topologies is important -

Comment: @LolFlo: In the sense of "having control"?

Comment: No, as in observing -

Comment: @LolFlo: I'm sorry, but I don't understand how track can mean observe or catalogue.

Comment: - _- maybe it is just an English euphemism.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note, for completeness. The suffix -aggio is considered, by purists, a "francesismo" (French words or rules incorrectly applied to Italian). An old way, correct for purists, has suffix "-tura": for example, verb lavare would give lavatura. On the other hand, some of these inpure words are now so common that they must be accepted; people would laugh hearing lavatura instead of lavaggio (but they would understand correctly anyway).

There is not a fixed rule to obtain a substantive from a verb and sometimes it is impossible. A way, sometimes, is to use the suffix -zione: perlustrare -> perlustrazione, other times you can take the past participle.

With regard to your question about "percorrere l'insieme", "percorso" could do, but probably a native speaker would not express that way, preferring perhaps visione, analisi, scansione or still other words.

Comment: Thanks for that information....

Answer (score 1):

There's no general rule to build the noun from a verb. Italian derives from Latin, so most of those nouns also derive from Latin nouns. There are some suffix patterns like *-aggio*, but as I told you, there is no general rule.

For the verb "percorrere", the noun is *percorso*, which means "path".

Good luck with your Italian learning.